# FOR XML EXPLICIT formatting output

Tags: sql-server, for-loop

I have a table with the following structure:

```
------------------------------------
invoice_id | device_id | terminal_id
------------------------------------
1          | SY000001  | GP000001
1          | SY000001  | GP000001
1          | SY999000  | GP999000
2          | SY111001  | GP111001
```

I want to get the data from the table in the following format:

```
<a href="view_divece.aspx?id=SY000001">SY000001 [GP000001]</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
<a href="view_divece.aspx?id=SY999000">SY999000 [GP999000]</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
```

Currently I was able to get the result in the following format (without the delimiter " | "):

```
<a href="view_divece.aspx?id=SY000001">SY000001 [GP000001]</a>
<a href="view_divece.aspx?id=SY999000">SY999000 [GP999000]</a>
```

My query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    1 as tag,
    null as parent,
    'view_device.aspx?id=' + device_id [a!1!href],
    device_id + ' [' + terminal_id + ']' [a!1!]
FROM DEALERS_SIMPAYMENTS 
WHERE 
    invoice_id = 1
FOR XML EXPLICIT
```

Is this possible, and if it is, how?

SQL server 2008.

Comment: retagging: question is not XML related

Comment: Which **version** of SQL Server??

Comment: come on ! generating html with a sql query ??

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use this query to achieve your required result??

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT
    '<a href="view_divece.aspx?id=' + 
    t.device_id + '">' + t.device_id + ' [' +
    t.terminal_id + ']</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp'
FROM DEALERS_SIMPAYMENTS t
WHERE t.invoice_id = 1
```

Returns two strings:

```
<a href="view_divece.aspx?id=SY00001">SY00001 [GP00001]</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp
<a href="view_divece.aspx?id=SY999000">SY999000 [GP999000]</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want a HTML fragment rather than XML. In this special case I'd go for string concatenation. Something like:

```
SELECT '<a href="view_divece.aspx?id=' + device_id + '">' + 
       device_id + ' [' + terminal_id + ']</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;'
FROM DEALERS_SIMPAYMENTS
WHERE invoice_id=1
```

should do the trick. This just works for your simple example of course and does no XML/HTML-escaping for funny characters in your data and such nice things. It also returns the entries in seperate rows. I don't know if that is a problem or not.